# Adding a second legend for vertical lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to add a second legend for 6 vertical lines I've added onto a `ggplot2` line plot representing 1 of 2 events instead of labelling the lines using the `annotate` function. I've tried this code but I'm not having much look:

```
p<- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = size, group = size)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(1,9,11), linetype="dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(5,14,17), linetype="dotted") +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = 'Events',
                        values = c('Closures' = 3,
                                   'Opening' = 3))
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible and filter out code that is not relevant for the problem? (e.g. theme settings or fancier labels)

Comment: can you dput(data)

Comment: I've not used that function before, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to do this could be to use `mapping=` to create the second legend in the same plot for you.  The key is to use a different aesthetic for the vertical lines vs. your other lines and points.

First, the example data and plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:25, 4), y=rnorm(100, 10, 2), lineColor=rep(paste0("col",1:4), 25))

base_plot <-
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=lineColor)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Greens")
base_plot
```

[image]

Now to add the vertical lines as OP has done in their question:

```
base_plot +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(1,9,11), linetype="dotted", 
            color = "red", size=1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(5,14,17), linetype="dotted", 
             color = "blue", size=1)
```

[image]

To add the legend, we will need to add another aesthetic in `mapping=`.  When you use `aes()`, `ggplot2` expects that mapping to contain the same number of observations as the dataset specified in `data=`.  In this case, `df` has 100 observations, but we only need 6 lines.  The simplest way around this would be to create a separate small dataset that's used for the vertical lines.  This dataframe only needs to contain two columns: one for `xintercept` and the other that can be mapped to the `linetype`:

```
verticals <- data.frame(
  intercepts=c(1,9,11,5,14,17),
  Events=rep(c("Closure", "Opening"), each=3)
)
```

You can then use that in code with one `geom_vline()` call added to our base plot:

```
second_plot <- base_plot +
  geom_vline(
    data=verticals,
    mapping=aes(xintercept=intercepts, linetype=Events),
    size=0.8, color='blue',
    key_glyph="path"   # this makes the legend key horizontal lines, not vertical
  )
second_plot
```

[image]

While this answer does not use color to differentiate the vertical lines, it's the most in line with the Grammar of Graphics principles which `ggplot2` is built upon.  Color is already used to indicate the differences in your data otherwise, so you would want to separate out the vertical lines using a different aesthetic.  I used some of these GG principles putting together this answer - sorry, the color palette is crap though lol.  In this case, I used a sequential color scale for the lines of data, and a different color to separate out the vertical lines.  I'm showing the vertical line size differently than the lines from `df` to differentiate more and use the linetype as the discriminatory aesthetic among the vertical lines.

You can use this general idea and apply the aesthetics as you see best for your own data.

Answer (score 1):

What about `geom_label`?

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~x, ~label,
  1, "first",
  1.5, "second",
  5, "third"
)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = 1)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = x)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = label))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>